# cakephp model validation not working

Tags: cakephp

I've searched and applied almost all suggestions i could find but still facing the same issue. I don't know why my model validation isn't working. Its a simple register page. can any one guide me through this. Here's my code below..

```
View - 
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
 <label>Username:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->text('username'); ?>
<label>Email:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->email('email'); ?>
<label>Password:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->password('password'); ?>
<label>Address:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('address'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Register')); ?>


Controller - 
public function register() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->User->validates()){
            $this->User->save($this->request->data);
        }
    }
}

Model - 
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'rule' => array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'A username is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
    ),
    'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'A password is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
    ),
    'email' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'rule' => array('email','isUnique', 'on' => 'create'),
            'message' => 'A password is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
    ),
    'address' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
    )
);
```

The problem I'm facing is when I hit on register, it enters blank entries. My db structure has "yes" in the "null" attribute for every field here.when I make them "no" it gives the standard integrity violation error.

Comment: although cake php validation is allowing null entries, which i still haven't solved, i'm currently using "required"=>true in form elements to avoid that case. if anyone can think of  reason why it doesn't work i'll be appreciative. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use create before the save call. Also there's no need for set and validate. Save will call validate for you.

Comment: Also not reusing the set data is wrong. He should have called save() without any params in his code example above.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to work. i'm using cake 2.5.6 in a local xampp. maybe some configuration is wrong set.

Answer (score 0):

Change view to `echo $this->Form->inputs(array ('email', username'....)` which should add the fields OK.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to work. is there any difference using form->input and form->text/email. they form the same html though.